# Flow with SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, reactive-programming

Trying to understand and implement how `Flow` works under the hood with `Room` and `SQLite`.

For instance in `Room`, following code will allow to respond to data changes. Is there some kind of observable on the database that allow to propagate changes to the listeners.

```
fun getAll(): Flow<List<User>>
```

How can a Flow based approach be implemented to using plain vanilla approach using the following code.

```
fun getAll(): ArrayList<User>? {
    val sql = "SELECT id, first, last FROM user"
    var users: ArrayList<User>? = null
    connection.readableDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null).use { cursor ->
        if (cursor.count > 0) users = ArrayList()
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            users?.add(User(cursor))
        }
    }
    return users
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190615/how-to-listen-for-sqlite-database-changes-in-android

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html

Comment: I don't know for sure since I haven't dug into the source code, but I assume the design is that Room keeps an internal registry of listeners that it notifies every time there is a change made by some DAO function. Each Flow/Observerable/LiveData returned by a DAO, when collected, registers a listener that executes a query and emits the result. When collection is cancelled, it would unregister the listener. If Room is really sophisticated, it might smartly be able to tell whether certain database operations wouldn't affect a specific query so it can avoid running unnecessary ones.

Comment: I think it could be as simple as wrapping with Flow<List<Users>>  IDK I got the room database to work so I don't need to do SQLLITE cursors anymore.

Comment: Is room database library opensource? can I look into source code of it?

Comment: Progressing, https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1 talks about database triggers and InvalidationTracker, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/InvalidationTracker